# How to use Azure npm packages without async?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

Due to depreciation, I am trying to update my code to the following 2 packages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos

The issue I am having is that my code currently uses packages that were pre async/await, whereas all the documentation for the newer packages assume use of async functions.

I would like to update my code's functions but without restructuring it with async functions. Is there any documentation out there on how to do that? Or any clear and easy examples?

For example, I am using this example to upload a blob:

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const account = "<account>";
const defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  defaultAzureCredential
);

const containerName = "<container name>";

async function main() {
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

  const content = "Hello world!";
  const blobName = "newblob" + new Date().getTime();
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
  const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(content, content.length);
  console.log(`Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);
}

main();
```

I would like to do so without async/await, and for `blockBlobClient.upload` use `function(err, result){ do stuff}` as my code already has.

Similarly, I would like to do so with `@azure/cosmos` functions.

My current packages are:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb
https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage

Is this possible?

I would really prefer not to restructure all my code...

Thanks

Comment: Could you please why you do not want to async? As far as I knew, Azure function supports async. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#exporting-an-async-function

Comment: @JimXu I am trying to update my code because the previous packages are depreciating. But I don't want to rewrite all of my previous code (which was pre async) as that would take a very long time...

Comment: As far as I knew, the new sdk returns Promise, we need to use await call function

Answer (score 0):

For any methdods that returns a promise, you can still use the call back approach:

```
blockBlobClient.upload().then((response) => {
  // do something with the response...
});
```